# How to configure the Attributtes forms to show the historic table related to 'n' records in QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-form

I have a point geometry layer that correspond to objects to street lamps. For each point I have the key field "CODE_ID".

[image]

On the other hand, I have a maintenance history table. This table stores the "CODE_ID" field, the "DATE" field and the "DESCRIPTION" field.

[image]

Both objects (geometry and table) have the key field "CODE_ID".

My goal is to configure the `Attributes form` of the geometry layer so that it shows in some way the maintenance history that has been done for each geometry object

My first approach to finding a solution is to create a `Join` between the geometry layer and the table:

[image]

Then I would like the `Identify features` tool form to somehow show that each point has 'n' related maintenance table records ordered by date.

For example, a solution for me would be to be able to see the joined field "STREET_MAINTENANCE_DATE" as a dropdown list, which when selecting a date shows me the corresponding content of the "DESCRIPTION" field.

How should I have the `Attributes form` configured for the "STREET_MAINTENANCE_DATE" and "STREET_MAINTENANCE_DESCRIPTION" fields so that they behave this way?

For now, for the "STREET_MAINTENANCE_DATE" field I have chosen the Widget Type Value Relation with the following information:

[image]

However, the result is not what was expected. The "STREET_MAINTENANCE_DATE" field appears as a disabled dropdown list.

[image]

I would like to ask you for your approach and your experience (best practices) to complete this kind of work. If it's possible, I would like to ask you for the maximum details of `Attributes form` configuration (options, expressions,...) necessary to achieve this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a `relation` between the geometry layer layer and the table having the extra data.

Go to `project/properties/relations/add relation`. Make sure to give a name to the relation.

[image]

Then open the geometry layer properties, `custom form`.
Opt for the `drag and drop` designer. Add fields from the geometry layer, then drag and drop the relation you have just created.

[image]

Now when opening the geometry layer attribute table or the feature info, you will also see the related table information. You can switch between a list or a table

[image]

Comment: This proposal solves my objective. Answer accepted. But, if possible, I would like to know is it possible an alternative to achieve the same with the `join` support and the use of some expression on **Attributes form**, to show a dropdown list as I comment in my question

Comment: @IngridIngravida The Join tool will only do one-to-one joins so not suitable for your use case. JGH's answer is the ideal approach. You can change the display expression in the list of child features (shown as a1, a1, a1 in the last image) to show the date instead, so you can instantly click on a date and see the corresponding info on the right hand panel. Either select dropdown at Expression in the child form, or set it up permanently in the child layer's Properties (Display > Display Name), also configure the Attributes Form to drag and drop designer, to only show the date and comments

Comment: @IngridIngravida If you really want a dropdown list GUI then you need to carry over the data to your parent layer but may not be good practice. Create 2 additional fields in parent layer: (1) date field called `DATE_SEL` with Value Relation widget, Layer = STREET_MAINTENANCE, Key and Value = `DATE`.  Filter expr = `current_value('CODE_ID') = "CODE_ID"` , (2) comment field with text edit widget (can disable editing); default expr (apply on update) = `aggregate('STREET_MAINTENANCE','array_agg',"DESCRIPTION",attribute(@parent,'CODE_ID') = "CODE_ID" and attribute(@parent,'DATE_SEL') = "DATE")[0]`

Comment: You will get [this result (GIF)](https://i.imgur.com/IrgXVTC.gif) but it saves the actual data in your parent layer which isn't really appropriate. Whereas if you change the display expression as mentioned earlier you get [this result (GIF)](https://i.imgur.com/VRwI6hX.gif) in form mode